# Sightly condition check

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

Below is my code.  actually i am displaying list of children (in 2 sections) on click in header navigation.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-sly-list.level1="${header.mainNavPages}" >



<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">

<ul class="dropdown-list" data-sly-list.level2="${level1.children}">

<li data-sly-test="${level2List.index <= level1.mainNavForkIndexValue}"></li>

-----------

</ul></div>



<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">

<li data-sly-test="${level2List.index > level1.mainNavForkIndexValue}"></li>

----

</ul></div>
```

Now my requirement , i want to display same results in 3 sections, i want to segregate the list of children in 3 sections (3 divs).

Earlier  2 sections (50% in first sections and another 50% in 2nd section)

```
"${level2List.index <= level1.mainNavForkIndexValue}",   ${level2List.index > level1.mainNavForkIndexValue}">
```

Now 3 sections (30,30,40 or  33,33,34%)

I need suggestion for sightly condition on how to achieve this.

Comment: From the provided code and without some kind of visual explanation how the end result should look like, it is hard to help you. Never forget, you are looking at the problem for a while now, we just read it about it. So please provide as much useful information as possible. The HTML for example is poorly formatted, hard to read and from our perspective it is broken since tags are opened,  but never closed etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for the container div. Try using flex and then style accordingly.

Here's an article on the same 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap grid system to display the three columns. You can have a look at the below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp